# ROS fuerte wifi support?

Tags: ros, wifi, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Where can I find info about what is actually implemented in ROS fuerte from this list:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Planning/IPC/WiFiNeeds

Especially a network-monitor would be interesting for me (I'd like to scan for networks + log the signal strength etc.).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32390/ros-fuerte-wifi-support?/) by [Cav](https://answers.ros.org/users/1633/cav/) on ROS Answers with karma: 345 on 2012-04-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That page is looking at how to make ROS work over lossy links, without worrying about the underlying implementation.

I think you're really looking for http://ros.org/wiki/linux_networking and the wpa_supplicant_node package. The documentation is pretty thin, but you should be able to figure it out.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2012-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cav](https://answers.ros.org/users/1633/cav/) on 2012-04-23**:
yep, that looks good. thanks.